# Android: google plus app integration for content comments

Tags: android, google-plus

I have created an app which has different content pages. Every page has an unique ID. I want the user to get into interaction with these pages by commenting or asking questions.

I want to have a separate google plus webpage for my app. The content in google plus does not yet exist but should get generated if a user comments a page for the first time. I also want to browse through all comments by web browser.
Is there a prefered way to do this or a tutorial for my problem? Thanks
Tata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is probably not possible at the moment due to this limitation: Note: The Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public data. All API calls require either an OAuth 2.0 token or an API key. - okay facebook though